# Caching a large SQL query - best way of structuring?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, optimization

Let me give an example of my issue. Let's say I have a table called **users** and a table called **payments**. To calculate a user's total balance, I'd use a query to get all the payments after a certain date and then cache the result for a while.

However, I was wondering, due to the nature of this, would it be a good idea to have a column in the users table called `balance` and then when the cache expires, I use a different query to gather the payments but from a shorter time and then add this amount on to whatever is in the `balance` column?

Comment: "*would it be a good idea*" - depends on your application.  How often do you update the balance?  How often do you need to fetch it?  What different queries do you use to do the latter (MySQL caches query results automatically, which is useful so long as identical queries are issued)?

Comment: The balance would be updated every time a payment has been paid, however the changes to the user can be delayed (a cache of a few minutes or something). The query itself would change on a per-user basis, and the results would change very frequently (based on the number of payments). As well as another factor; time of payout.

Comment: I usually have columns `something_cache` and functions to regenerate these completely. I don't think a function to regenerate them correctly *only most of the time* isn't any good. But as eggyal said, it really depends on your application.

Comment: You could update a balance column on the `users` table and update it with a trigger.

Comment: How often do payments happen per user? How many payments happen per user? Do you only need the total until now, or do you need to be able to query the past. If the past is interesting to which level of differentiation, e.g. is it okay per month or per year?

Comment: @hakre - payments would be happening daily per user. This varies a lot per user, though. Erm, I'd say around 2 months into the past for this particular query.

Comment: Do you actually have a problem?  Is your querying slow?  It sounds like you are guessing that you have a performance problem, but have no measurements.  Any optimization that is done without measurement is premature.

Comment: @AndyLester Not currently, I'm just preempting. But the query could get really large, and I will be caching, I was just wondering if it would be best to have a balance column, too, instead of calculating it each time.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @eggyal I just didn't want to have to re-do a lot of it further down the line had I not thought about all of this beforehand :P

Comment: You are talking about fixing a problem that very well might not be a problem.  You have no idea how severe the problem might be.  Maybe your .5 second query takes .6 seconds instead.  Is that worth the expense you're putting into it?  The expense of fixing this not-yet-a-problem is the time spent to come up with this solution, and the ongoing cost of having data that you must forever work at keeping in sync with each other.  Consider also that programmer time is orders of magnitude more expensive than computer time. Most of all, **you don't have a problem**.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely right there. I just didn't want to have missed something out, or not thought about it when writing it.

Comment: @AndyLester I don't agree with that. OP clearly states that he is expecting a lot of data within a year. Its plain to see that he will soon have a problem

Comment: @YarekT: No, it's not plain to see that he will soon have a problem.  It's plain to see that he *might* have a problem.  Without measurement, you're guessing.  You have no idea how the database will perform.  You have no idea how much data he is going to have other than "a lot".  You know nothing about the hardware he's running on.  Even he has no idea how much data he'll actually have.  Everything stated at this point is conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

> To calculate a user's total balance,

You can create an additional table that always contains the users current balance. If a new payment is added for the user, that column needs to be updated, too. Do a transaction so adding the payment and updating the total balance is aligned.

If you need this more differentiated, you can next to the user relation, keep a date column representing the interval you need to be able to do calculations for. E.g. the week number or month number to be able to give a view back in the past.

If you need more flexibility, you can after some time compress existing payments into a total value and store that into such a balance table that is user-related and keeps a date column.

You can then UNION it with the table of the payments that are "realtime" for the dates not yet compressed / condensed. Then use an aggregation function to SUM the total balance. This might give you the best of both worlds if you need to keep recent data with more detail you can move out of the data-store after some time, just keeping statistic values.

Comment: I see. So instead of calculating the balance each time, I can just read it from a balance column. This works, but it just didn't seem very "dynamic" to me, if you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Prash: No, but I extended the answer for two branches you can go into from that basic idea that both add more dynamic.

Comment: btw, was the first like meant to say column, or table?

Comment: A table of it's own with a column for the userID and a column for the total to store the aggregated value. This is basically like map-reduce. Just mapping/reducing each time you update the main table.

Comment: May I ask why? Instead of just having a column for their total in the users table? :)

Comment: Because the users table is likely to be properly normalized, while doing aggregation is not. Also it will allow to add the date-column to map with different resolutions and do the UNION I wrote about later. You can't do that while putting that into the users table. But for the very beginning it's just not in there because it does not belong in there. It probably even does not belong at all into a relational database, but that is a more differentiated discussion.

Comment: Ahh. So the aggregated value is stored in a separate table, and any additions will be summed using that value. I see! One row per user?

Comment: @Prash: That depends on the level of differentiation you need. If you only need a total value, that is one row per user then.

Answer (score 2):

Generally with these kinds of "pre-calculated" values I find that the most pain free way is to store/update them on save of any model that concerns the data

So in short, update the total balance whenever a new payment is saved. That way you can guarantee that your database and your data will always be in sync

The pre-calculation can be either a mysql trigger or a background task with something like Gearman

---

But as your own question suggested if you want to do some kind of incremental roll-up of the balance, I would advice going by months or some fixed date range. This would work providing that you have no payment backdating or something like that, where payment could appear for an old month.

Start of the new month, run a payment aggregator, bam, you now only have to sum the monthly tables.

It all really depends on how much data you have to deal with. But again I stress, data consistency is a lot more valuable than speed, you can always buy more servers.

Comment: Yeah- your last point, that's the reason why I was a bit hesitant of having a static `balance` column.

Comment: Are you expecting too much data to aggregate in a query? (say on update, or even a background task?)

Comment: Not too much data. What would you consider too much data?

Comment: @Prash the quantity is relative to the server power that you have. If the query that does the calculation for the entire dataset of data for  2 years or so takes less than a second, then it would be ok as a trigger. If your server is slower than you expect, maybe you should aggregate